# Ionic full size background

Tags: ionic-framework, background, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to give my app a full-sized background. But I don't really know where to put it because wherever I put the image the navbar hasn't the background.

So I tried to surround my ion-content and my ion-footer with a `<div>` and hoped to give it the background-class. but in this case nothing I can't see anything on the screen. Right now my background is only inside the ion-content and the footer is still empty. How can I change it?

My code:

```
<ion-content class="bg-image" padding>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>

  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you can see **[in the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/#input-properties)**, you need to add the `fullscreen` property to the `ion-content`:

```
<ion-content fullscreen="true">
    <!-- ... -->
</ion-content>
```

> If true, the content will scroll behind the headers and footers. This
>   effect can easily be seen by setting the toolbar to transparent.